# Unpack fields from object passed as function parameter in js

Tags: javascript, destructuring, object-destructuring

```js
const user = {
  id: 42,
  displayName: 'jdoe',
  fullName: {
    fname: 'John',
    lname: 'Doe'
  }
};

function whoIs({
  fullName: fn = {
    fname: "john",
    lname: "doe"
  }
}) {
  console.log(`${fn.fname} ${fn.lname}`);
}
whoIs(user);
```

Let's assume I have destructured user object in multiple function parameter and I want to change fname property to firstName but I don't want to change the implementation in all functions.

```
user.fullName.firstName = user.fullName.fname;
delete user.fullName.fname;
```

How can I unpack user so that I just have to make changes in function parameter?

Comment: I think there is a typo in you whoIs function parameter list. Please fix that.

Comment: You can destructure `const { fullName, ...rest } = user;` and after then you can create a new object `const newObj = {
    ...rest,
    fullName: { firstName: fullName.fname, lastName: fullName.lname },
  };`

Comment: I don't think it is possible to change only in parameters and you can make changes...

Answer (score 0):

You are not destructuring the `fname` property, only the `fullName` property, in your parameter list. So you cannot change the `fname` property name without changing also the implementation of your function.

Answer (score 0):

You can destructure and rename properties like this:

Where `fname` is destructured and renamed to `firstName` and `lname` is destructured and renamed to `lastName`

```js
const user = {
  id: 42,
  displayName: "jdoe",
  fullName: {
    fname: "John",
    lname: "Doe",
  },
};

function whoIs({ fullName: { fname: firstName, lname: lastName } }) {
  console.log(firstName, lastName);
}

whoIs(user)
```

Answer (score 0):

this solved my issue

```
function whoIs({
   displayName:dn="jdoe",
   fullName:{firstName: fname = "john",lname = "doe"}={}
  } = {}) {
    console.log(dn+" "+fname+" "+lname );
}
```

also now I can call function without passing argument.